# IIS6 and .Net 4.5?

Tags: iis, iis-6, .net-4.5

In the past, the .NET framework has been independent from IIS versions, and have worked with IIS 6+.

Will IIS 6 be supported for .NET 4.5?

Comment: Isn't it about time to accept an answer already?

Answer (score 19):

IIS 6 is part of Windows Server 2003 (and technically XP 64-bit).

The [.NET Framework 4.5 System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx) indicate that Server 2003, thus IIS 6, is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to throw the last answer off, this could be a typo on MS website, but looking for the same question, I found this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733890.aspx

"WCF can also be installed on Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 R2, or Windows Server 2003 SP1"

and that is while I have .net 4.5 selected at the top.

I am thinking typo.. but hopeful ;)

Comment: I believe it is a mistake on that page. The .NET Framework 4.5 installer will refuse to even run on Server 2003 / XP. WCF *can* run on those operating systems, but only with .NET 3.x or 4.0.